# jQuery 1.5.2 get fullscreen event Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to capture the event of fullscreen (fullscreen on and fullscreen exit)

Using the latest I was successfully able to achieve this with:

```
 $(document).on('mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange fullscreenchange',function(){
         alert("fullscreen capture");
     });
```

Using jQuery 1.5.2

Any ideas?

I understand to use `.live()` and `.delegate()`, but I wasn't able to capture this event.

Comment: Have you thought of using regular js?

Comment: It's a huge project I can't make this kind of changes, I just want to get it done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to do this in an old version of jQuery.

```
$(document).bind('mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(){
    alert("fullscreen capture");
});
```

P.S. `.live()`/`.delegate()` are for "delegated" events.  That is, binding events to elements that may not exist at that time.  In newer jQuery versions, you would do:

```
$('#parentElement').on('click', '.child', function(){})
```

Comment: Ah ok, I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the [firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API):

> When fullscreen mode is successfully engaged, the document which contains the element receives a mozfullscreenchange event. When fullscreen mode is exited, the document again receives a  mozfullscreenchange event. Note that the mozfullscreenchange event doesn't provide any information itself as to whether the document is entering or exiting fullscreen mode, but if the document has a non null `mozFullScreenElement`, you know you're in fullscreen mode.

To get this information for all major browsers use

```
var fullscreenElement = document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement;
var fullscreenEnabled = document.fullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullScreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled;
```

Also check this [site](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen) for a lot of usefull tips and code regarding the fullscreen event.